# Website html become messy unexpectedly

Tags: css, apache, boonex-dolphin

I have a server with a dolphin boonex sofware installed, 7.1.4 version (boonex.com). However, I don't think the boonex fact is part of the problem. I guess, other webmaster, whatever the platform they use, can experiment the same issue.

Sometimes, when I load my website, everything becomes messy. It likes it losts CSS. Look a te the picture below

[image: Messy website, reason not identified]

Normally everything is fine : links are nicely fitted in a top bar menu, template is correct, and so on. Now, it looks like there is no more CSS linked to the HTML. But it is (in the code)!

Just before this happened today, i had just change a small setting in my .htaccess. But it is not linked : when I de-set the setting, nothing went better. Also, I experiment such a problem a couple days by month, and it likes it comes "random".

I would like to know what kind of apache failing (I guess it is) can explain such a problem kinda CSS failing).

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools, is the CSS file loaded?  What is the server's response for the request to the CSS file?

Comment: Seconding the question asked by @David ... in the developer tools, is the file being loaded? And is it being sent as "text/css" or something else? I think you're right that it's a missing CSS file.

Comment: I went have lunch, and everything went back to normal now. I knew that would be the case, because it's not the first time i experiment this. I'll wait for the pbm to reappear and then I'll verify if the file is loaded (such a good idea, thank you!). I'll update this topic if I have any new element to add, in order to help people with same issue.